# Python 2.6 bindings for SVN 1.6.6

Tags: svn, trac, visualsvn-server, python-2.5

I'm trying to install Trac 0.11 on Windows XP with Python 2.6 and VisualSVN server (Subversion 1.6.6) but I can't seem to find working bindings.

Comment: not programming related. See http://superuser.com instead.

Comment: I had seen other related questions like that on SO so I thought it was okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution: http://www.visualsvn.com/server/trac/

VisualSVN has a special trac plugin for use with their server.